# dbt install -snowflake fails with cryptography and MarkupSafe being outdated

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, github-actions, dbt, python-cryptography

Installing dbt in a virtual environment using pip install dbt-snowflake has been failing with the following error:

```
ERROR: pyopenssl 22.1.0 has requirement cryptography<39,>=38.0.0, but you'll have cryptography 36.0.2 which is incompatible.
ERROR: werkzeug 2.2.2 has requirement MarkupSafe>=2.1.1, but you'll have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

The snowflake package seems to have older version of cryptography and MarkupSafe. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: I just tested it on a macOS and worked fine for me using a venv and this step: **pip install dbt-snowflake**. What steps have you followed exactly and what other packages did you already have installed in your env?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same issue, I fix it by pinning the pyopenssl version `pyopenssl==22.0.0` this version has a minimum dependency `cryptography>=35.0`

The newer pyopenssl version had a dependency change of `cryptography>=37.0.2` and this conflicts with snowflake-connector requirement of `cryptography==36.0.2`